# Estimation Of Mappers for a cluster

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, sqoop

Need some clarifications regarding the estimation of mappers for a particular job in Hadoop cluster. As per my understanding the no of mappers depends on the input splits taken for processing . But this is in the case if we are gonna to do processing for input data residing already in HDFS . Here I need clarification regarding the mappers and reducers triggered by a SQOOP job . PFB..

1. How mappers count are estimated for a dedicated cluster,based on RAM or based on the input splits/blocks?(In General)
2. How mappers count are estimated for a sqoop job for retrieving data from an RDBMS to HDFS based on input size?(Sqoop based)
3. what is meant by core CPU’s and how it affects the count of mappers that can be run parallel?(Genaral)

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Number of mappers are not counted based on cluster size or ram size. it is automatically determined by number of input splits.
2. Number of mappers --m (n) argument in sqoop syntax can be determined based on RDBMS table size and required column size
3. CPU have nothing to do with Count of mappers

please read this Hortonworks Data Platform : Cluster Planning Guide
:https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.0/bk_cluster-planning-guide/bk_cluster-planning-guide-20150721.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need some clarifications regarding the estimation of mappers for a particular job in Hadoop cluster. As per my understanding the no of mappers depends on the input splits taken for processing . But this is in the case if we are gonna to do processing for input data residing already in HDFS . Here I need clarification regarding the mappers and reducers triggered by a SQOOP job . PFB..

1. How mappers count are estimated for a dedicated cluster,based on RAM or based on the input splits/blocks?(In General)

answer : No it has nothing to do with the RAM size. it all depends on the number of input split.

2. How mappers count are estimated for a sqoop job for retrieving data from an RDBMS to HDFS based on input size?(Sqoop based)

answer : by default the number of mappers for a Sqoop job are 4. you can change the default by using -m (1,2,3,4,5...) or --num-mappers parameter , but you have to make sure that either you have primary key in you db or you are using -split-by parameter otherwise there will be only one mapper running and you have to explicitly say -m 1.

3. what is meant by core CPU’s and how it affects the count of mappers that can be run parallel?(General)

answer : core in CPU is the processing unit which can run a task. and when you say 4 core processor that means it can run 4 task at a time. the number of cores does not participate in calculating the number of mappers by mapreduce framework. but yes if there are 4 cores and mapreduce calculates the number of mappers are 12 then at a time 4 mappers will be running in parallel and after that rest will be running serially.

Comment: @Ramyaa Please accept my answer and vote up if it solved your query. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. How mappers count are estimated for a dedicated cluster,based on RAM or based on the input splits/blocks?(In General)

   You are right. **Number of mappers are usually based on number of DFS blocks in the input.**
2. How mappers count are estimated for a sqoop job for retrieving data from an RDBMS to HDFS based on input size?(Sqoop based)

   **By default, Sqoop will use four tasks in parallel to import/export data.**

   You may change this by using `-m <number of mappers>` option.
    **Refer: [Sqoop parallelism](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.4/SqoopUserGuide.html#_controlling_parallelism)**
3. what is meant by core CPU’s and how it affects the count of mappers that can be run parallel?(General)

   **[CPU cores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor) are processing units. In simple words "More the Cores the better.", that is if we have more cores it can process more parallely.**

   Example: if you have 4 cores, 4 mappers can run parallely.(theoretically!)